# « Ils veulent que ce soit gratuit pour polluer » : une figure de style ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, ponctuation, figure-de-style, formulation

Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-canadienne/201901/27/01-5212551-taxe-carbone-la-ministre-de-lenvironnement-denonce-la-polarisation.php) la ministre de l'Environnement du Canada, Mme [Catherine McKenna](https://www.noscommunes.ca/Parliamentarians/fr/members/Catherine-McKenna(88892)), déplore ce qu'on pourrait appeler sans conteste la bêtise conservatrice, dont l'ignorance, le manque d'éthique et le mensonge, concernant entre autres les opportunités d'affaires découlant des actions que commandent urgemment le contexte de changements climatiques indéniables, sont devenus monnaie courante aujourd'hui au Canada, aux États-Unis et ailleurs, vu entre autres, à mon avis, les bulles de filtrage dans lesquelles les particuliers sont pris en otage malgré eux par leur subjugation aux médias sociaux adossée à dessein par des entrepreneurs sans scrupules à une dépendance à la [dopamine](https://www.lapresse.ca/vivre/201802/09/01-5153270-dangereux-les-reseaux-sociaux.php).

> Mais la ministre McKenna déplore que les conservateurs qui s'opposent
>   au plan fédéral - « **ils veulent que ce soit gratuit pour polluer** »,
>   dit-elle - s'en servent pour diviser les citoyens. (La Presse, je souligne)

- Quand on parle ici d'une volonté de *gratuité pour polluer*,
  s'agissait-il d'un jeu de mot avec [*pulluler*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pulluler), était-il plus
  juste d'employer la préposition *de* (ce sens emportait-il un constat
  idéologique : la « liberté » de polluer ) ou s'agissait-il de l'équivalent de la locution
  prépositionnelle *afin de* (pouvoir), vu leur (absence) de plan dans
  le domaine et donc leur désir de *statu quo* : dans ce dernier cas la virgule était-elle souhaitable avant la préposition *pour* ; s'agissait-il d'une inversion (*que polluer soit gratuit*) ; y a-t-il ellipse de termes ? Peut-on s'appuyer sur sa compréhension du propos en contexte pour expliquer si la tournure idiomatique, cohérente : on reformulera au besoin ?

Comment: J'avoue que je ne comprends pas ce que la phrase veut dire. Mon intuition me dit que la phrase devrait être "*ils veulent que ce soit gratuit **de** polluer*", ce qui se pourrait venir d'une mauvaiser traduction de "*they want it to be free **to** pollute*", où syntaxiquement "*to*" peut être traduit par "*de*" ou par "*pour*" (même si ça n'a pas beaucoup de sens, sémantiquement).

Comment: Connaissant la presse, ça me semble très peu probable que ce soit une figure de style ou un jeu de mot, surtout étant donné le contexte (politique).

Answer (score 1):

Voici la signification de la phrase:

> «Quand c’est gratuit de polluer, il y a plus de pollution».

Source: [Taxe carbone et climat: le fédéral garde le cap, dit la ministre McKenna](https://www.lesoleil.com/actualite/politique/taxe-carbone-et-climat-le-federal-garde-le-cap-dit-la-ministre-mckenna-c0bc8e2d58ddfd04e35b7ba2f31c258f)

Ce n'est donc **pas** une figure de style, mais bien une simple erreur.